# Change Map Title Block Information through ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, layouts

I am new to python, but I'm currently working on a script tool to loop through all MXDs within a folder and change their associated title block information(Map Title, Report Title, Date, Charge Code, etc...) then export the newly MXDs to PDF.

I have no problem changing some of the static information that is the same for all MXDs such as the Date/Client/Report through arcpy.GetParameterAsText, but my real question is ...

Is there a way to allow for multiple titles?

For instance I know you can allow for multi-values and the output string looks something like "Exhibit 1 ; Exhibit 2; Exhibit 3 " Is there a way to take that string and split it into individual titles for each based off the order of the mxds in the folder?

Here is my current script :

```
    env.workspace = r"E:/Python/ENV_TEST"
clientTitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
reportTitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
dateTitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
PNTitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
titleList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"E:\Python\ENV_TEST\\" + mxdname)
    pdfname = mxdname + ".pdf"  
    for titleItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT", "Title"):
        titleItem.text = titleList
    for ReportItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT", "Report"):
        ReportItem.text = reportTitle
    for ClientItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT", "Client"):
        ClientItem.text = clientTitle
    for DateItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT", "Date"):
        DateItem.text = dateTitle
    for PNItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT", "PN"):
        PNItem.text = PNTitle
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,pdfname)
    mxd.save()
```

Comment: Did you try using wildcards? `Title*` would return Title1 and Title2. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayoutelements.htm

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a text element in your layout called Title. You'd like to replace the text of the element with variable titleList. I assume the value of the variable looks like "Exhibit 1;Exhibit 2;Exhibit 3".

If you want all the titles in a single text element on different lines you could do something like this. The code below assumes that titlelist looks like a string with titles separated by a semicolon, and the text element area is large enough to support multiple lines of titles.

Swap the semicolons for carriage returns:

```
titlelist= titlelist.replace(";","\n")
```

Then replace the text:

```
titleItem.text = titleList
```

or this way to clean up any spaces:

```
splt = [x.strip() for x in titlelist.split(";")]
titleItem.text = "\n".join(splt)
```

You can also get more sophisticated using formatting tags so you can have subtitles:

```
splt = [x.strip() for x in titlelist.split(";")]
result='<FNT size = "12">{0}</FNT>\r\n<FNT size = "10">{1}</FNT>\r\n<FNT size = "10">{2}</FNT>\r\n'.format(splt[0],splt[1],splt[2])
titleItem.text = result
mxd.save()
```

I realize that isn't too flexible since it is hardcoded to three titles. You would need to loop through in some way. I found using 10.2.2 on my machine only using the \n doesn't create a carriage return you need \r\n for it to work.
Edit: See @paul's comment for an explanation about \r and \n.

Comment: You need the carriage return `\r` because Windows EOL separator is CRLF - carriage return + line feed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Why would only be a problem when I used the formatting tags? It didn't seem to matter when inserting the text.